# Swift 3 HTTP Request with ByteBuffer, InpuStream, and HTTPS

Tags: java, swift, http, https, swift3

I am currently trying to break down the open source cups4j library and create a similar swift 3 implementation. I have recreated most of the application so far, but I am the point where Java and Swift differ strongly.

I am trying to use a `URLSession` and `URLConnection` to perform a POST request of what is known as an IPP Protocol. The problem here is I don't know how to handle the bytes and input stream in Swift. Even more so, what is the standard for HTTPS Certificate handling?

I am currently trying to convert this Java definition:

```
private IppResult sendRequest(URL url, ByteBuffer ippBuf, InputStream documentStream) throws Exception {
  // stuff
}
```

to this Swift implementation (Might be wrong?):

```
private func sendRequest(url : URL, ippBuf : Array<UInt8>, documentStream : InputStream) throws -> IppResult {
   // stuff
}
```

I have replaced all instances of `ByteBuffer` in the code to `Array<UInt8>` and simply use Swift's `InpuStream`. I am completely lost on the Certificate handing, where in java the X509Certificate is used.

See the full Java Function below:

```
private IppResult sendRequest(URL url, ByteBuffer ippBuf, InputStream documentStream) throws Exception {
        IppResult ippResult;
        if (ippBuf == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (url == null) {
            return null;
        }

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        mLastResponseCode = 0;

        try {
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", IPP_MIME_TYPE);

            if (url.getProtocol().equals("https")) {
                HttpConnectionManagement.handleHttpsUrlConnection((HttpsURLConnection) connection);
            }

            HttpConnectionManagement.handleBasicAuth(url, connection);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[ippBuf.limit()];
            ippBuf.get(bytes);

            ByteArrayInputStream headerStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            // If we need to send a document, concatenate InputStreams
            InputStream inputStream = headerStream;
            if (documentStream != null) {
                inputStream = new SequenceInputStream(headerStream, documentStream);
            }

            connection.connect();

            // Send the data
            copy(inputStream, connection.getOutputStream());

            // Read response
            byte[] result = readInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            mLastResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            // Prepare IPP result
            IppResponse ippResponse = new IppResponse();
            ippResult = ippResponse.getResponse(ByteBuffer.wrap(result));
            ippResult.setHttpStatusResponse(connection.getResponseMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mLastResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.e(CupsPrintApp.LOG_TAG, "Caught exception while connecting to printer " + url + ": " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
                if (((HttpsURLConnection) connection).getSSLSocketFactory() instanceof AdditionalKeyStoresSSLSocketFactory) {
                    final AdditionalKeyStoresSSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (AdditionalKeyStoresSSLSocketFactory) ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).getSSLSocketFactory();
                    mServerCerts = socketFactory.getServerCert();
                }
            }
            connection.disconnect();
        }

        return ippResult;
    }
```

Any help or direction or reference are much appreciated in advanced. Thanks!

Comment: Hi napkinstererror, did you get the solution. apparently i am also looking for the same thing. If you find any solution do share.

Comment: @JB29.4 What are you trying to work on? I was able to figure out some of this.